# Boot guard verified DXE that is failed

Tags: motherboard, uefi, firmware

I'm new to building computer,

I've just built my new PC:

- MSI Z97i ac gaming Mini ITX board
- i7 4790K intel processor
- 650W PSU
- Leadtek Geforce GTX 970
- Vengeance 16GB ram
- 128 GB SSD

I've just placed all this parts together and started it up. 
It shows "Boot guard verified DXE that is failed"

No matter how many times I've restarted it, it keeps showing this.

Did I accidentally broken the MotherBoard? Or could it be because I didn't install the drivers? 
I don't have an optical drive to install the drivers for now.

Comment: You can install drivers from a USB device.  You do have one of those right?  But this problem isn't a driver issue.  [You need to RMA your motherboard its defective](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=184488.0).  You can also flash the same version of UEFI twice after switching which one will be used.  Check your manual on how to switch between the primary and backup UEFI.

Comment: Your hardware provided MSI isn't just linked all its hardware to the same UEFI page does indeed have the "Multi-BIOS II" feature.  The manual for your board will explain how you can switch between the two.  The suggestion of flashing an update is a last ditch effort.  **You might just want to RMA it.**

Answer (score 0):

according to many this is a Bios issue. Basically your motherboard has 2 bios and during an update, only 1 was updated and not the other. you may have to flash both to make sure both are running the same version.

Comment: Also would like to add that contacting MSI would help clarify my answer.

Comment: DXE is " Driver Execution Environment" which is indeed part of the EFI framework and may be considered part of the BIOS, so without further information (which may not be possible) I think this is pretty close to the answer. If it was just purchased or is under warranty returning it may be the better option over flashing.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the motherboard needs to be replaced. I had to do that unfortunately.